# Some twitter posts have multiple Tweet IDs

Tags: twitter

I happened to find out that for Tweet post ID (e.g. 804443247653322753), when I try to open the page for this Tweet (through URL like https://twitter.com/PolitiFact/status/804443247653322753), it is automatically redirected to Tweet with different Tweet post ID. (e.g. above link will redirect you to https://twitter.com/PolitiFact/status/804418546168041472). It seems quite many Tweet post IDs can redirect to same single Tweet post. Does anyone know why this happens, or what's wrong with those redirected Tweet post IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, each tweet has an ID.
A RT is a tweet. So a RT has an ID.

The tweet ID 804443247653322753 has been posted by @hrblock_21 and it is a RT of the tweet ID 804418546168041472 posted by @PolitiFact.

So, this is done by twitter, the web site redirects automatically to the original tweet because it is the only tweet to see (except if the user added a comment when retweeting).

And you can even try https://twitter.com/anyUserName/status/804443247653322753, or https://twitter.com/anyUserName/status/804418546168041472, the tweet to see is the original so it redirects.