# Twitter4j not returning correct id of a tweet

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using Twitter4j for displaying some tweets in a java program. I need to show a hyperlink for each tweet which links to the actual tweet.

I am using the below format to get the URL:

```
https://twitter.com/{username}/status/{tweetid}.
```

To get the tweetid, I am using:

```
Twitter twitter = createInstance();
Query query = new Query("Obama");
List<Status> listStatus = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
Long tweetid = listStatus.get(0).getId();
```

The tweetid received from above doesn't match to the actual tweet's id. How can I get this working. Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Comment: If a tweet is a retweet of some tweet, then you can get original tweet information in `retweeted_status`.

Comment: May be related to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568339/some-twitter-posts-have-multiple-tweet-ids/51579272